# bundle.js is causing an "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2, axios

I'm pretty confused by this and can't seem to find anyone reporting a similar issue from bundle.js

Basically I am running a react/falcon website on an ec2 instance and it is working except for the axios post my website makes to a flask api i have set up.

the relevant code that invokes the axios post request is in my react.js webpage is:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('In CONSTRUCTOR');
    var postData = {
        queryString: this.props.location.search
        //queryString: this.props.location.search.split("=")[1]
    };
    let axiosConfig = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }
    };
    axios.post('http://172.31.26.109:5000/run_query', postData, axiosConfig)
    .then(function (response) {
        influencerList = response.data.query_results;
        console.log(influencerList);
    });
}
```

The following is the output in the javascript console when the page loads:

```
In CONSTRUCTOR
bundle.js:94878 GRGRGRGRGRGR!!!
bundle.js:94879 ?query=as
bundle.js:94886 DOING AXIOS
bundle.js:94887 {queryString: "?query=as"}
bundle.js:94888 {headers: {…}}
bundle.js:76560 parsing failed SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
bundle.js:14474 OPTIONS http://172.31.26.109:5000/run_query net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
dispatchXhrRequest @ bundle.js:14474
xhrAdapter @ bundle.js:14308
dispatchRequest @ bundle.js:14921
Promise.then (async)
request @ bundle.js:14725
Axios.(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:14745
wrap @ bundle.js:15182
Search @ bundle.js:94889
constructClassInstance @ bundle.js:59072
updateClassComponent @ bundle.js:60556
beginWork @ bundle.js:60942
performUnitOfWork @ bundle.js:62941
workLoop @ bundle.js:63005
callCallback @ bundle.js:53259
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ bundle.js:53298
invokeGuardedCallback @ bundle.js:53155
renderRoot @ bundle.js:63083
performWorkOnRoot @ bundle.js:63731
performWork @ bundle.js:63684
batchedUpdates @ bundle.js:63803
batchedUpdates @ bundle.js:55047
dispatchEvent @ bundle.js:56138
bundle.js:94895 Error: Network Error
    at createError (bundle.js:14847)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (bundle.js:14383)
```

I have no idea what is going on here and can't find anyone having a similar issue with bundle.js

anyone have any thoughts?

edit:

i just curled the endpoint for this method and realized the error makes total sense given the response the endpoint is giving me:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="http://172.31.26.109:5000/">http://172.31.26.109:5000/</a>.  If not click the link.[ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-109 backend]$
```

Obviously this is invalid json but i am totally lost as to why this is appearing as the response as this was not the case when running this on my local machine. I am getting a 301 response when curling so obviosuly there is some issue with my redirects or something on the server. Thoughts?

Comment: The response you got was bad JSON. Axios is trying to parse it and failing and throwing

Comment: Remove the `Content-Type` header and log the response that you get. Maybe you'll find something.

Comment: On a sidenote `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is to be set on the server.

Comment: You can also see the response in the `network` tab of Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Axios follows redirect, in your logs i can see `http://172.31.26.109:5000/run_query net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` so axios actually followed the redirection link but reached a timeout, probably because your server is down or crashed.